# get random data from table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Questions TABLESAMPLE (100 ROWS) 
order by NEWID()
```

It returns the same 10 records every time but they are in a different sequence.  How can I get a different set of 10 random values each time?

Comment: Are you trying to ask something...?

Comment: If you are only looking for 10 random rows, you can remove the `TABLESAMPLE (100 ROWS)` and have what you want.

Comment: It sounds like the order of the rows' appearance is not to your liking. How do you want it to be ordered?

Comment: Without the TABLESAMPLE in a table with a million rows your generating 1 million guids then sorting them as opposed just 100

Comment: Per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx): "If you really want a random sample of individual rows, modify your query to filter out rows randomly, instead of using TABLESAMPLE."

Comment: i want to save the result into another table?

Comment: @Kailas I have updated my answer to try and show you how you would insert the random values into a table.  If it isn't what you were looking for, let me know and I can try to update to suit your needs

Answer (score 3):

If you just want 10 random rows, this will work for you:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Questions
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

You do not need the `TABLESAMPLE (100 ROWS)` here

---

In order to save the results to another table as indicated by your comment you would be able to do this easily if the second table exists.  Then you can:

```
INSERT INTO RandomQuestions(col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT TOP (10) q.col1, q.col2, q.col3, ...
FROM Questions AS q
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I'm worried that the last edit makes big assumptions about the OP's intent.

Comment: @TimLehner I understand, and that was a consideration of mine before I made the edit. I believe I am correct, and hope that if I am not, the OP will clear up any misunderstandings by editing their question. If someone disagrees with me and reverts my last edit, I would understand that completely as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to order your random records.  You might do that using a derived table (where I'm aliasing a sub-query, below):

```
select *
from (
    -- Derived table to get 10 random rows
    select top 10 * 
    from Questions
    order by newid() -- Here we are randomizing the entire table.
) as a
order by a.QuestionID -- Here is where you can order your 10 random records.
```

Do not use `tablesample` if you truly need random records, per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108.aspx):

> If you really want a random sample of individual rows, modify your query to filter out rows randomly, instead of using TABLESAMPLE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP ### FROM Questions TABLESAMPLE order by NEWID()
```

Replace ### with the number you rows you want. This is based on the OP's idea.